# how get the position of vertex from window form in c#?

Tags: c#, python, css, user-interface

I have been started with wireless sensor network simulator, and I want to simulate my own topology , which need to make the rings that connect the vertices with each other ( boundary hull). 
I am seeking to get the position of every vertex which are  represented on the window form ( graphical) and which are a neighbor of other vertices and connect them with each other , but I want to make the connection between the nearest vertices , (the vertices that have smallest radiuses between each other)[wireless sensor network simulator ( node (vertex) deployment)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz1CZ.png).

my question is that , how can I get the position of every vertices? 
the code 4bellow is the way that I tried to calculate the reduise 
int r1  = (int)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(firstNode.x - ((WirelessSensor)firstNode.SensorNeighbors[count]).x, 2) + Math.Pow(firstNode.y - ((WirelessSensor)firstNode.SensorNeighbors[count ]).y, 2));
int r2  = (int)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(firstNode.x - ((WirelessSensor)firstNode.SensorNeighbors[count+1]).x, 2) + Math.Pow(firstNode.y - ((WirelessSensor)firstNode.SensorNeighbors[count+1]).y, 2));

Comment: I fear this question is too broad for you to receive a good answer on Stack Overflow. You should add some more detail to help narrow the realm of possibilities. You should describe what you have tried so far and where you are struggling. Including specific code segments from the areas you are struggling in will help as well.

Comment: I tried more for calculating the distance between two vertices because i want the smallest radius  so then I choose the small one and compere it with other vertex until I find the smallest one between the neighborhood of one vertex then make the connection between them , I can't calculated using the x and y coordinate it fail to find the smallest .

Comment: @KevinBurdett  help me please I stack here for a weeks :(